What do the double negative and multiple uses of otherwise here mean?

"I quite agree with you," said the Duchess, "and the moral of that is
— 'Be what you would seem to be'— or, if you’d like it put more
simply—'Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might
appear to others ... to be otherwise.“
"I think I should understand that better,“ Alice said very politely,
"if I had it written down: but I can't quite follow it as you say it."

from Fromkin's Introduction to Languages, which wrote that the above quote was from LEWIS CARROLL, Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, 1865.

"It's a mineral, I think," said Alice.
"Of course it is," said the Duchess, who seemed ready to agree to
everything that Alice said: "there's a large mustard-mine near here.
And the moral of that is-- 'The more there is of mine, the less there
is of yours.' "
"Oh, I know!" exclaimed Alice, who had not attended to this last
remark. "It's a vegetable. It doesn"t look like one, but it is."
"I quite agree with you," said the Duchess; "and the moral of that
is-- 'Be what you would seem to be'--or if you'd like it put more
simply-- 'Never, imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it
might have been was not otherwise than what You had been would have
appeared to them to be otherwise.' "
"I think I should understand that better," Alice said very politely,
"if I had it written down: but I'm afraid I can't quite follow it as
you say it."

from http://ilg-ul.github.io/historic-webs/eunet/alice/alice_12.html
What do the Dutchess mean? What do the double negative and multiple uses of otherwise mean?

"Mean?" The point of Alice's response is that the sentence is incomprehensible; she can't tell what it means. There's a bit of comedy there about trying to communicate politely to people in elevated social stations that they're not making sense. We could try to parse the sentence seriously, but that's not really how we're meant to handle nonsense literature. Voting to close.

I’m voting to close this question because it tries to make sense of a sentence that was explicitly designed not to yield a reasonable meaning.

Imagine reading Alice in Wonderland and thinking it would all make sense if only you understood English a bit better. That must be torture.

There's a typo, you wrote the year 1355,  it should be 1865


Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might appear to others ... to be otherwise.

Cross out two negatives:

Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might appear to others ... to be otherwise.

Imagine yourself to be otherwise than what it might appear to others... to be otherwise.
When in the company of others, imagine yourself to be different from the impression they have of you in order that you may always think yourself to be other than the self you believe they believe you are.

Thanks. is "imagine yourself to be different from the impression they have of you" consistent with  'Be what you would seem to be'?

No, it is rather the opposite. Imagine yourself to be other than you think you appear to others.

Then does the duchess contradict herself?

She is giving advice, not declaring any fact, so how can she be contradicting herself?

Isn't "be otherwise than what it might appear to others ... to be otherwise“ the opposite of  'Be what you would seem to be'?

The final clause "... to be otherwise" is a statement of purpose, i.e. "[in order] to be otherwise".  In order to be other than people's impression of who you are, imagine you are different.  The advice assumes that Alice can somehow intuit what people think of her.
